# New github repo which will fork pre-existing project: same or different name?

Tags: github

I am going to create a new github repo with the intention of forking a pre-existing public open-source project.  Let's say the pre-existing project is https://github.com/foobarguru/foobar.  Let's say I'm brec.  Should my new repo be named foobar or something like foobar-brec?  In other words should I use the same name (foobar) since access requires use of my name anyway and that sufficiently  distinguishes the repo from the pre-existing one, or a distinct name?

Comment: If you fork it from GitHub's site it will create the repo for you.

Comment: @vcsjones. Thank you.  It created the equivalent of [...]github.com/brec/foobar.  That was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

2021:

To add to [vcjones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492405/vcsjones)'s comment, [GitHub Fork help page](http://help.github.com/fork-a-repo/) does mention the only operation yu have to do is to click on that fork button:

[image: fork button]

The name of the forked (cloned on GitHub side for your account) repo will be the same than the original repo you have forked.

---

2022: the name of the fork... can [differ from the original repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71849165/6309)!

Comment: This is also the preferred way to fork a project on github, because this way github itself will mark the project as "fork", so everybody can see it (and -- I don't exactly -- as far as I know pull requests are only possible between forks).