# Github: Forking after removing fork

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I've removed my fork but now I cannot fork same repo again. I just see Github's 404-page when trying to "re-fork". How I can fork now?

Comment: Where exactly do you see that 404 page?

Comment: What do you mean? Github just shows it Not Found -page when I try to fork. Nothing more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find a similar behavior with old versions of GitHub for Enterprise, as illustrated in the [issue 50](https://github.com/rose-compiler/rose/issues/50).

The [recommendation, for forks on GitHub](https://github.com/rose-compiler/rose/issues/50#issuecomment-10475260), is to wait a few hours after deleting the previous fork, and try again ([clicking on that fork button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8698907/6309)).

Note that you shouldn't have to delete a fork if you intent to make new pull requests: simply isolate them in their own branch after having updated your fork ([pushing to origin the latest from upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257533/what-is-the-difference-between-origin-and-upstream-in-github/9257901#9257901)).

See also (to avoid deleting a fork):

- "[My pull request has been merged, what to do next?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770550/my-pull-request-has-been-merged-what-to-do-next/12772000#12772000)"
- "[How to do a Github pull request?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681796/6309)"
- "[Pull request without forking?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14821866/6309)"

Comment: I can confirm the delay. I deleted my fork of `rails/rails` and tried to re-fork it right away, getting a 404. After about 30 minutes, I was able to fork it again.